# iOS Dropbox SDK on Device fails login with NSURLErrorDomain

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ipad, dropbox

UPDATE: Setting the Dropbox SDK to use HTTP instead of HTTPS cures this problem on an iPhone 3G.  I haven't used the SDK on iPhone 4 or iPad yet so I'm not sure of the result.

Playing with the Dropbox SDK on iOS yields these results:  in simulator, I can properly link my account using the provided login form class.  Changing the build setting to device, I get an error alertView triggered by this method in DBLoginController.m

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loginFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
    [self setWorking:NO];
    NSString* message;
    if ([error.domain isEqual:NSURLErrorDomain]) {
        message = @"There was an error connecting to Dropbox.";
    } else {
        //...
```

The login form is displayed like so, as referenced in the included sample project:

```
-(void)settingsPressed {
if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        DBLoginController* controller = [[DBLoginController new] autorelease];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [controller presentFromController:self];
    } else {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] unlink];
        [[[[UIAlertView alloc] 
           initWithTitle:@"Account Unlinked!" message:@"Your dropbox account has been unlinked" 
           delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]
          autorelease]
         show];
        [self updateButtons];
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what to make of this.  Apple docs suggest that NSURLErrorDomain is defined as NSURL loading system errors.  Can anyone shed light on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should look at is `error.code` or better `[error localizedDescription]`

`NSURLErrorDomain` is a **vast** error domain :

> Constants used by NSError to differentiate between "domains" of error codes, serving as a discriminator for error codes that originate from different subsystems or sources

An error in NSURLErrorDomain could be almost anything, connection down, proxy, certificate errors... Search for `NSURLError` in that [apple documentation page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: I disabled HTTPS in the Dropbox SDK and it works fine on iPhone 3G.  I haven't tested my iPhone 4 yet

Comment: `-[error localizedDescription]` would probably have gave you that explanation, avoiding some monkey testing.... ;)

Comment: then errorcode + so/google would have probably done the trick, thanks for accepting :)